# How to specify VPC ID in cdk FargateService

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I'm trying to create multiple ECS services each service as a different stack so I can update/delete/recreate them individually. I have 2 more stacks one for VPC and another one for the ECS cluster.

Structure:

```
.
|-- README.md
|-- stacks
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- ecs.py
|   |-- iam.py
|   |-- tasks_services.py
|   |-- test.py
|   `-- vpc.py
|-- app.py
|-- cdk.context.json
```

In my app.py I'm fusing thig together

```
vpc = vpcstack(app, "vpcstack", config,
         env=cdk_env
               )
cluster = ecsstack(app, "ecsstack",vpc,config,
               env =cdk_env
               )
ExecutionRole = executionRole (app, "role" , environment,
                            env=cdk_env)

service = mySvc (app,"initial",environment , config,cluster,vpc,
                         env =cdk_env)
```

I'm not sure how to pass the VPC values into the `ecs.FargateService`

```
    ecs.FargateService(self, "Service",
                       cluster=cluster,
                       task_definition=task_definition,
                       vpc_subnets = ec2.SubnetSelection(                             
                            subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_NAT
                                    ),
```

It gives the error
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'selectSubnets')` makes sense because it was not able to read the VPC properties. I don't see any option to specify the VPC values here.

For example `ec2.securitygroups` has the VPC paramerter
`self.security_group = ec2.SecurityGroup(self, "SG", vpc=vpc)` How to do the same for `ecs.FargateService`

Passing the VPC construct to the ECS cluster, (i have combined the VPC and clustre togather for ease of use ).

**Creating VPC/cluster:**
in ecs.py

```
            vpc = ec2.Vpc(self, "VPC",
                               max_azs=3,

            ecs.Cluster(self, "Cluster",
                              vpc=vpc
```

Comment: VPC should be of type VPC, not a Stack.

Comment: @gshpychka you mean don't create a separate stack for VPC?  embed that with the cluster stack ?

Comment: No, I meant that you should be passing the VPC construct to the cluster, not a Stack that has the VPC construct in it.

Comment: Tried like that but `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'vpcId')` still it's the same. Not able to get the VPC details from the cluster (while creating the service)

Comment: That's because you're not passing the VPC construct. Update the code in the question so we can help.

Comment: Update the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244103/discussion-between-ajr-and-gshpychka).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @gshpychka for pointing out the exact issue. Took some time to understand.

Extract VPC for the stack and pass it to the next stack

```
vpc = vpcstack(app, "vpcstack", config,
         env=cdk_env
               )
cluster = ecsstack(app, "ecsstack",vpc.vpc,config,
               env =cdk_env
               )

service = mySvc (app,"initial",environment , config,cluster.ecs_cluster,vpc,
                         env =cdk_env)
```

In VPC.py

```
class vpcstack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, config,**kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        # VPC constructs
           self.vpc = ec2.Vpc(self, "VPC",
```

in ecs.py

```
class ecsstack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, config,vpc,**kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        # Cluster 
        self.ecs_cluster = ecs.Cluster(self, "Cluster"
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.Cluster.html#example) the information about VPC is passed through a `Cluster`. Thus when creating a cluster you should pass in a correct VPC reference.

```
cluster = ecs.Cluster(self, "Cluster",
    vpc=vpc
)
```

Comment: I did actually and passed the `cluster` to the service
`ecs.Cluster(self, "Cluster",
                              cluster_name=config.cluster.name,
                              vpc=vpc
                              )`